# Проблема со стилями при вложенности

Tags: html, css

Есть проблема со стилями при вложенности

```
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <style type="text/css">
   .t1 p {
    color: blue;
   }
   .p1 {
    color: red;
   }
  </style>
 </head> 
 <body>
    <div class="t1">
        <p>Абзац 1</p>
        <p class="p1">Абзац 1</p>
        <p class="p1">Абзац 1</p>
    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

т.е. у класса p1 цвет не красный. Можно class="p1" заменить на id="p1", тогда работать будет, но по логике одинаковых id быть не должно. Как с этим бороться?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Достаточно сделать **color: red !important;** или же продумывайте структуру не только HTML-разметки, но и CSS

Answer (score 1):

```
<style type="text/css">
   .t1 p {
    color: blue;
   }
   .t1 p.p1 {
    color: red;
   }
  </style>
```

думаю дальше разберетесь.